# unable to connect ms sql server from Presto in Qubole

Tags: sql-server, azure, presto, qubole

I am using Qubole Data Service on Microsoft Azure. I have created Presto Cluster in Qubole. I want to connect to MS SQL Server from Presto to read data from MS SQL Server. I have created sqlserver directory on "/usr/lib/qubole/packages/presto-0.157/presto/plugin" this path and added the following jars:
presto-base-jdbc-0.180
presto-sqlserver-0.180
mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8

Also added sqlserver.properties file to /usr/lib/qubole/packages/presto-0.157/presto/etc/catalog

```
sqlserver.properties:
connector.name=sqlserver
connection-url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx
connection-user=root
connection-password=xxxxx
```

Error:

> Query 20171215_134323_00008_jzzyq failed:
>   com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.SemanticException
>
> Catalog sqlserver does not exist
>
> com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitTable(StatementAnalyzer.java:777)
>
> com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.StatementAnalyzer$Visitor.visitTable(StatementAnalyzer.java:244)
>
> com.facebook.presto.sql.tree.Table.accept(Table.java:53)
>
> com.facebook.presto.sql.tree.AstVisitor.process(AstVisitor.java:27)

Comment: And? Do you get an error string? A timeout? Have you tried to connect with any other program? Given that the administrator password in SQL Server is *not* `root`, are you sure you are using the correct credentials?

Comment: yes the credentials are correct. I have added the error in the question.

Comment: Did you read the error? `Catalog sqlserver does not exist`. You tried to conenct to a database called `sqlserver`.

Comment: Its a catalog name sqlserver. and I am not connecting to any specific database, connecting to ms sql server only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution.
when i added the same configuration of `sqlserver.properties` file to `edit cluster settings -> advance configuration -> Override Presto Configuration`. It worked.